# Causes for "The report source cannot be retrieved from the state object."

Tags: crystalreports, businessobjects

Posted this on SO as well, but figured it's more likely to be a server config issue so I'm hoping someone knows what's going on here.

I have a legacy system that has a CMS server set up to generate Crystal Reports all from the same database. Users will input the required parameters in a front end application, which then passes it to the CMS to generate the report in a CrystalReportViewer.jsp page. The report titles as shown in both the CMC console and InfoView is as follows:

```
PersonnelDetailsA
PersonnelDetailsB
PersonnelDetailsC
```

After a recent update to the application (which did not touch on the Crystal Report functionality at all), users reported that they were unable to generate a report for PersonnelDetailsB (A and C were both working fine). The stated error message that they got was

```
Report source could not be retrieved from the state object
```

After some googling and trial and error on our development setup, I figured out that the error was caused by the CMS not being able to find the report requested, so my immediate, and actually only, hypothesis was that the report name my application passed to the CMS was wrong (the only way I've managed to reproduce the error). So I went and verified it in the production InfoView.

Turns out I was dead wrong. All the report names are correct.

As far as I know, nothing has changed with the set up of the CMS in production. The reports worked fine prior to our application update and I've verified that we did not make any changes in our application that would affect the Crystal Report functionality. In fact all the reports work perfectly in our development setup. Yet something clearly went wrong when we deployed to production. All 3 reports are in the same folder, and yet one of them cannot be found even when the correct report name is provided.

What am I missing here? What other way would cause the CMS to throw that specific error beside not being able to find the report in question?